# Create trigger to only allow updates for certain employees

Tags: sql-server, triggers

We have a database with one table for all of our Employee information, (name, pay, etc). One of the columns in the table is "commission." I am trying to write a trigger that will only allow the "commission" column be updated or inserted into if it is for a Sales Representative. If an update is tried on any other employee then it should print out an error. I would like this trigger to also print all of the information from each update, failed or not, to a separate table. What is the best way for me to go about doing this?

I am relatively new to SQL Server so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

EDIT:
Here is what i have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CommissionUpdate ON Employees
FOR UPDATE
AS IF UPDATE(Commission)
Declare
    @Old_Comm money
    , @New_Comm money
    , @EmpID int

Select @EmpID = (Select EmployeeID From Deleted)
Select @Old_Comm = (Select Commission From Deleted)
Select @New_Comm = (Select Commission From Inserted)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ChangeLog (EmpID, [User], [Date], OldComm, NewComm)
    VALUES (@EmpID, User_Name(), GetDate(), @Old_Comm, @New_Comm)
END
```

Basically all this does is add entries to the ChangeLog table when the commission table is updated. Im still having trouble adding the constraints to only allow "commission" to be updated for Sales Reps.

Comment: You could define a *Check Constraint* in SQL-Server.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Look into "INSTEAD OF" Triggers.  The trigger runs instead of the actual insert or update, and you can add processing to raise errors, do the insert or update only if certain conditions exist, and copy data to a second table. But remember that in a trigger, the "inserted" and "deleted" collections may (and probably will) always carry more than one row, so write set-based SQL accordingly.

Comment: I just updated my description with what i was able to get so far. I was able to get it to past the information i needed in the "ChangeLog" table but i am still having trouble only allowing changes to be made to "commission" for sales reps

Comment: When working with triggers remember that inserted and deleted can contain more than one row